# YT Video loop and controls not working

Tags: html, video, iframe

Alright so I made this video to clear all controls that it has & to be on a constant loop & autoplay BUT there are 2 problems

1. Video will stop at the end & it will not go into a loop as it should (aka it should just start again)
2. YT sign still appears on the video eventho controls are disabled.

Code

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/g09xdJ3hmHw?rel=0&loop=1&autoplay=1&iv_load_policy=3&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8yfsxxkz/)

Answer (score 0):

you won't be able to remove the YT logo overlay (though it fades out after a few seconds of the video playing)

to fix the looping you need to fix you embed code - you have a couple of `&amp;` when you probably just meant `;` and didn't include the `playlist` parameter which, per [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#loop), is required when looping

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/g09xdJ3hmHw?rel=0&loop=1&autoplay=1&iv_load_policy=3;controls=0;showinfo=0&playlist=g09xdJ3hmHw" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
```